# Unable to iterate through array

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get some data from the local server while parsing json. In a view controller I access **local Ruby on Rails server**:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    var url = NSURL(scheme: "http", host: "0.0.0.0:3000", path: "/api/search?query=auto")
    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {(data, response, error) in
    var data1: NSDictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary
        println(data1)
        println(data1["companies"])
        var companies = data1["companies"] as NSArray
        for company: AnyObject in companies {
            println(company)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

`println(data1)` returns:

```
{
    companies = "[{\"alias\":\"02-avtomoyka-tulybaev-r-t\",\"id\":45693},{\"alias\":\"1001-zapchast-internetmagazin-avtotovarov\",\"id\":42621}]";
}
```

With `println(data1["companies"])`, I've got array of objects in the console:

```
[{"alias":"02-avtomoyka-tulybaev-r-t","id":45693},{"alias":"1001-zapchast-internetmagazin-avtotovarov","id":42621}]
```

Then, when I'm trying to iterate through that array, the app crashes. What am I doing wrong?
It stucks with no errors in the console, but `(lldb)` and `EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_I386_BPT, subcode 0x0)` in Tread 6

PS: Also Xcode throws the compiler issue `Constant 'company' inferred to have type 'AnyObject', which may be unexpected` at `for company in companies {` string. How can I handle it?

Comment: Could you provide the error and edit your query for much clearer understanding.

Comment: @walle84 I've added more code, hope this helps.

Comment: For that compiler warning, change your for loop to `for company: AnyObject in companies { ... }`

Comment: @NateCook Thank you, but still've got EXC_BREAKPOINT on `libswift_stdlib_core.dylib swift_dynamicCast: 0x1c1150:  pushl  %ebp` string

Comment: I'm confused by the output of `println(data1)` -- from where did you copy/paste that? If you're really seeing those backslashes, maybe the JSON didn't deserialize properly.

Comment: @NateCook Thank you very much. I've solved the problem with your hint. The problem was in json, which I generate on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `var companies = data1["companies"] as NSArray` try `var companies = data1["companies"].allValues;`

The problem is `data1["companies"]` is a dictionary and can't be implicitly converted to an `NSArray`. The compiler doesn't catch this because `data1["companies"]` is stored in `NSDictionary` as `AnyObject` and will allow you to cast it to any subclass.

Comment: Thanks, but `data1["companies"].allValues` returns nil either for well-formed json and not. The problem solved with correcting json generation.